# Technical Interview: Longest Non-Decreasing Subsequence in MxN Matrix

Tags: algorithm

I was recently asked this question in a technical interview. Here is my solution. http://pastebin.com/JMVHcfRq Did I make a mistake or is there a better solution?

> Find the length of the longest non-decreasing sequence through adjacent, non-repeating cells (including diagonals) in a rectangular grid of numbers in a language of your choice. The solution should handle grids of arbitrary width and height.
>   For example, in the following grid, one legal path (though not the longest) that could be traced is 0->3->7->9 and its length would be 4.
>   8 2 4
>   0 7 1
>   3 7 9
>   The path can only connect adjacent locations (you could not connect 8 -> 9). The longest possible sequence for this example would be of length 6 by tracing the path 0->2->4->7->7->9 or 1->2->4->7->7->8.
>   Write a method, in a language of your choice, that takes a rectangular grid of numbers as input, and returns the length of the longest such sequence as output.

Comment: Is there a restricion on what adjacent cells you can move to? For example, can you only move to the right and/or down?

Comment: Also, you have a `v` matrix in your code that is not being updated.

Comment: the v matrix(visited) is to keep track of the current path through the matrix and updated as a cell is visited.

Comment: The movement restrictions are just that the adjacent cell must be >= to the current cell and you can't visit a cell you've been to already.

Comment: You link is broken. (Which is exactly why) code should be pasted directly into the question, not linked to. And if it was code, I'd suggest changing it to a few lines of pseudo-code or a high-level description instead.

Answer (score 6):

You can model your problem with directed graph:

Each cell is vertex in your graph and there is an edge from C<sub>i,j</sub>→C<sub>k,m</sub> if two cells C<sub>i,j</sub>,C<sub>k,m</sub> are adjacent and C<sub>i,j</sub> < C<sub>k,m</sub>.

Now your problem is finding longest path in this graph, but this graph is Directed acyclic graph, because as problem says there isn't repeated number in matrix also "<" relation is anti symmetric. So your problem reduced to find longest path in directed acyclic graph, which is easy by first doing topological sort then finding longest path . e.g see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#Acyclic_graphs_and_critical_paths).

**Update:**
At first glance I thought is impossible to have equal neighbors but now I see is possible, In the above graph construction we should replace < with <= then sure graph is not acyclic but still problem is equal to find the longest path in this graph.

P.S1: If I have any polynomial answer for this longest path problem I'll bring it here, but may be by this classification of problem is easier to search around it.

P.S2: as [mbeckish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21727/mbeckish) mentioned in comments, the [longest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) is NP-Hard in general graph, but I think in this special case can be solved in P, but I don't have exact algorithm right now.

P.S3: I do a little research on it, I saw, [Hamiltonian path in grid graph is NP-Complete](http://books.google.de/books/about/Hamilton_paths_in_grid_graphs.html?id=Vta6GwAACAAJ&redir_esc=y), So seems your problem is also NP-Complete (I don't have reduction right now but they are very close to each other).

Comment: I thought about using a directed graph, but in this case there can be repeated adjacent numbers potentially creating a cycle. So a simple topological sort through a DAG doesn't help much.

Comment: Your criteria "Ci,j < Ck,m" is strictly increasing, not strictly non-decreasing.  If you change it to "Ci,j <= Ck,m", then you have to also check for cycles every time you add an edge where Ci,j = Ck,m.

Comment: @mbeckish, See problem statement: "non-repeating cells" means two neighbor are not equal at all, I used this fact to say it's anti-symmetric. Also user2196041 I think I answered to you by this comment.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri - You are correct.  The question is just worded poorly.

Comment: I believe non-repeating in this scenario means that you can't make a repeat visit to a cell(So each cell can only be visited once). In the given example they visit each 7 once. So yes there is potential confusion on wording

Comment: @user2196041, If you interpret the question in this way, I agree with you, but again it will be longest path to this special grid (just replace < with <= to make your graph), If I have any algorithm for this, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Using @user2196041's interpretation, your graph will have cycles, which would turn this into the [Longest Path Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem), which is NP-Hard.

Comment: @mbeckish, Longest path is NP-Hard for general graph, but this is very special case, I think it's in P, and I think I have a very dirty and non efficient algorithm for this graph (is planar, grid, every vertex has degree at most 8), but I'm not sure if is correct and I cannot think in an interview someone asks to write very complicated code. e.g I think first find elementary cycles then find longest path inside each elementary cycle between each two vertex, then paste them to border, ... this is my general thought on it, but if some company in interview wants this I'm not going to work there.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri I don't think there is a reduction of Hamiltonian Path on the grid to this problem; you can't model every finite subgraph of the grid with matrices described in the question. Specifically, you can't model two vertices that are adjacent on the grid but not in the subgraph: for every pair (v,w) of adjacent cells of the matrix, the graph has v->w or w->v, you have no way to model v and w being non-adjacent. So there are subgraphs of the grid you can't model, which means no reduction - unless there's some error to this.

Comment: @G.Bach, this is simplest way for thinking about reduction, there is no need to convert evry grid to this graph, you could also have subgraph in this graph which is equal to some grid, then say finding large path in our graph causes to make hamiltonian path on its underling grid graph, the simple way is routing path inside each region of grid in some good way. (If obvious thing doesn't work, doesn't mean there is no way).

Comment: @SaeedAmiri That doesn't seem correct to me; this would imply that it is enough to model a clique, which has every finite subgraph of the grid as a subgraph.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri   can't we just do a `DFS in 8 directions with constraint that next node >= current ` on every cell and check for longest path ?. In worst case (all elements are equal) we may have to do N^4 operations but algorithm is actually `O(M^2)` , where M is size of input i.e. N^2 ?

Comment: @anon I cannot see how dfs finds a longest path? DFS just finds some paths (or may be approximation of longest path), but if you want to do dfs with backtracking it will find it in O(2^n), which is not very efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution takes exponential time (in the size of the matrix) in the worst case.

To speed it up, use [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), or bottom-up [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

Comment: I doubt that OP can change his algorithm to bottom up one, because visited and unvisited case in his algorithm is not easy to change, would you show that how he can improve mentioned algorithm to run it in P?

Answer (score 1):

Also using n dijkstra calls (reverse it to find max path) you can solve it in O(n^3). Using a max heap can lower it to 0(n^2 log n). When building the graph, only create edges to neighbors that are >= to the current vertex.

I tried the topological sorting but I found cycles in the graph. Need to check my code.

Comment: If by reversing Dijkstra we can find longest path then we can show that P=NP.

Comment: Good point Saeed, longest path is an NP problem. Do you have a counterexample for an unweighted graph like the one described in this problem?

Comment: If you define your graph as my way and define edge weight as 1, then there are tones of counterexample furthermore when you claim something you should prove it not looking for counterexample and if you see there is no counter example saying it's correct, I'd offer you to read about [russel's teepot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_teapot)

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm not claiming my solution is correct. In fact, I did say you had a good point about N=NP. Just wanted to see if you had a counterexample handy.

Comment: I know you didn't claim this (because of this I just left a comment for you), and I know you just looking for handy counterexample, but as I said your graph definition is not clear to me, Also if I suggest you to check Russel's teepot is just for your information in general and for your future not this answer, because is simple to fall in this trap.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the good reading. In terms of graph definition, while constructing the graph I skip edges between adjacent neighbors when the origin vertex has a higher value than the destination. So in this example 0, 7 and 2 have direct edges to 8, but 8 has no edges. The weight for each edge is 1 as you said.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the starting indexes not to test are those that are included in longer paths, which include all the lists of allowed 'next indexes' for all indexes.

So I first mapped the allowed next indexes for each index and removed all of them from the group of starting indexes to test:

```
*Main> indexesIncludedInLongerPaths
[2,0,4,6,1,7,8] (numbers 4,8,7,3,2,7,9)
```

which left two indexes to test:

```
*Main> indexesToTest
[3,5] (numbers 0,1)
```

After that, I searched all paths from those starting indexes and returned the longest.

```
*Main> nonDesc matrix
[[1,2,4,7,7,9],[0,2,4,7,7,9]]
```

Haskell code:

```
import Data.List (nub, delete, sortBy, groupBy)

matrix = [8,2,4
         ,0,7,1
         ,3,7,9]::[Int]
m = 3
n = 3

neighbors index
  | index == 0           = [1,m]
  | index == m - 1       = [m-2, 2*m-1, 2*m-2]
  | index == m*n - 1     = [m*n-2, m*(n-1)-1, m*(n-1)-2]
  | index == m*(n-1)     = [m*(n-1)+1, m*(n-2), m*(n-2)+1]
  | index < m            = [index+1, index-1, index+m, index+m-1, index+m+1]
  | index > m*(n-1)      = [index+1, index-1, index-m, index-m-1, index-m+1]
  | mod index m == 0     = [index+1, index-m, index+m, index-m+1, index+m+1]
  | mod (index+1) m == 0 = [index-1, index-m, index+m, index-m-1, index+m-1]
  | otherwise            = [index+1, index-1, index-m, index+m
                           ,index-m+1, index-m-1, index+m+1, index+m-1]

indexesIncludedInLongerPaths = 
  nub $ concatMap (\x -> [a | a <- neighbors x
                              ,matrix!!x <= matrix!!a]) [0..length matrix-1]

indexesToTest = 
  foldr (\a b -> delete a b) [0..length matrix-1] indexesIncludedInLongerPaths

nonDesc matrix = solve indexesToTest [[]] where
  solve []     result = last $ groupBy (\a b -> length a == length b)
                        $ sortBy (\a b -> compare (length a) (length b)) 
                        $ map (\x -> map (\y -> matrix!!y) x) (concat result)
  solve (x:xs) result = 
    let paths = solve' [x] 
    in solve xs (paths:result)         
      where solve' y = 
              let b = [a | a <- neighbors (last y)
                                ,notElem a y
                                ,matrix!!(last y) <= matrix!!a]
              in if null b
                    then return y
                    else do a <- b
                            solve' (y ++ [a])
```